# Howto access properties file from Java EE web application?

Tags: java, eclipse, properties

I have created a dynamic web project within Eclipse. I created a properties file inside the src directory:

```
<project-root>/src/props.properties
```

I'm starting Tomcat via Eclipse in debug mode. Now I want to read the properties file from one of my POJOs, but I get a FileNotFoundException. The current path seems to be the Eclipse path.

I had a look into the web for solution, but none of them worked for me. Maybe I did something wrong. The code is like this:

```
File file = new File("props.properties");
FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
properties.load(reader);
```

How should I acces the properties file?
Where should it be located?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 23):

If its a web application then the properties will get deployed to WEB-INF/classes and can be loaded using the class loader

```
InputStream in = {NameOfClassWhereThisisInvoked}.class.getResourceAsStream("/props.properties");
properties.load(in);
in.close();
```

Actully that should work regardless of whether it is a webapp or not.

I'm assuming src is defined as a source folder

Comment: Thanks all for answering. I forgot to mention that I'm starting tomcat via eclipse. The properties file is copied to: C:\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\WebAppName\WEB-INF\classes. Now I have a copy of the props file in the project root and in src folder, but I am not able to acces it anyway.

Comment: Where is your pojo class?  The above assumes they are both loaded by the same classloader

Comment: This is the way to go. It's better to load resources via a classloader to avoid dependencies on local file system arrangement, current working directory etc. The resource location has to be on the classpath of course, so WEB-INF/classes is a good place.

BTW if you omit the slash - getResourceAsStream("props.properties") - the resource is expected in the same package as the current class.

Answer (score 3):

There is another way of doing this as follows:

```
File file = new File(session.getServletContext().getRealPath("/") + "props.properties");
```

Instead of "props.properties" you could give any path relative to the "WebContent" folder of your eclipse web-application project.

Answer (score 2):

here is the correct way to load properties file from anywhere in the classpath

```
private Properties getPropertiesFromClasspath(String propFileName)
                                                                throws IOException
{
    Properties props = new Properties();
    InputStream inputStream =
    this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFileName);

    if (inputStream == null)
    {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("property file '" + propFileName
      + "' not found in the classpath");
}

props.load(inputStream);
return props;
}
```

You can create a singleton class to load properties in memory on first time access and later use them via a static method. A complete example of this is available at
http://bharatonjava.wordpress.com/2012/09/12/using-properties-file-in-java-application/

Comment: You should probably elaborate on why this is better / what the trade off is vs calling getResourceAsStream on the class rather than the classloader.

Answer (score 1):

Kepp ur Properties file in src folder and the following code is enough to read the properties file

```
  **File file = new File("./src/config.properties");
  FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
  prop.load(reader);
  System.out.println(prop.getProperty("directorypath"));**
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your project set to build automatically? If so (or you're building manually), check whether`props.properties` appears in your project's **output** folder (in Eclipse this is usually "bin" but may be WebRoot or something else, depending on how your project is set up).

When a project builds, it should copy over config files as well as your compiled classes, JSPs etc. However, I believe that file readers, by default, use the JVM's home directory for their source. In Eclipse's case, this means that your `props.properties` file would have to be in the project **root**, i.e. not the "src" folder.